# Python socket error thrown with IP addresses

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to connect 2 remote computers at different locations.

Everytime i added my public IP address in the parameter, an error is thrown.
`OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

This is the server side code i used in this project:

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = **PUBLIC IP**
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr):
  print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

  connected = True
  while connected:
      msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
      if msg_length:
          msg_length = int(msg_length)
          msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
          if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
              connected = False

          print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
          conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

  conn.close()


def start():
  server.listen()
  print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
  while True:
      conn, addr = server.accept()
      thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
      thread.start()
      print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

Comment: You can't bind to your public IP if you're behind a router, you need to bind to the private IP. The router performs the address translation.

Answer (score 0):

Set `SERVER = '0.0.0.0'` to bind to the server's IP.